# HttpRequest is making me upset

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpresponse

I was trying to use the HttpRequest methods on java but it doesn't work, this is my code

```
package com.example.phpconnect;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.util.Log;

public class httpHandler {

public String post(String posturl){

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);
        Log.w("Se envio","Fase 1");

        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();          
        Log.w("Se envio","Fase 2");

        String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
        Log.w("Se envio","Fase 3");
        return text;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.w("Se envio","Error");
        return "Error";
    }

}

}
```

It works fine up to the first log, then it throws the error, please some one know where the problem is? thanks!

Comment: How about some details on what the exception is, like the stacktrace maybe.  Tough to figure things out without that.

Comment: I don't get that, I just have that code, and my MainActivity, do I have to post that code too?

Comment: Inside your catch block you need to log the stacktrace from the `Exception e`.  I'm not an android person, but typically, you just do `e.printStackTrace` and this goes to `System.out`.  If you can't do that, at least log the message from the `Exception` like so: `Log.w(e.getMessage());`

Comment: In looking at the android Log API docs, you can log the stacktrace like so: `Log.w("httpHandler", e);`

Comment: Can't see the error log, but I bet you're passing an invalid URL. It should be encoded. One way is `URI.encode(string)`. Oh, and love the title :)

Comment: this is what I get when I use Log.w("httpHandler", e);
http://pastebin.com/DbHCPw2d

Answer (score 0):

> NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

As correctly pointed out in comment by @EJP, will just try elaborating it.

HTTP Post request should not be executed in Main Thread. It needs to be run in background and for that you may use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and execute it in `doInBackground()`.

[More details on Exception!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)